# Can't create the page in the Store View programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Can't create the page in the Store View programmatically.

I have two stores:

1. English
2. French

   ```
   $pageModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
       ->create(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory::class)->create();
   $pageModel->load($submission['content_id']);
   $pageModel->setId(null);
   $pageModel->setContent($content);
   $pageModel->setStoreId($storeId);
   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
       ->create(\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface::class)
       ->save($pageModel);
   ```

Result:

```
$origialStoreId = 1;

$storeId = 2;
```

**Could not save the page: URL key for specified store already exists.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because URL rewrite rule - `url_rewrite` table:

```
UNIQUE KEY `URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
```

Make two test cases:

1) Create a CMS page: **Page in Websites > All Store Views**

Take a look at `url_rewrite`. A record will be generated for each store.

[image]

So, in this case, your code above will have an error. Because Magento will try to insert the same row to database.

2) Create a CMS page: **Page in Websites > Choose a specific store**

Now we can use your code above.

Should take a look module cms and url-rewrite for more details.

**Suggestion:**

-Should use `$pageModel->setStores($storesArray)` to set stores for the cms page.

For example:

```
$pageModel->load($storeId);
......
$pageModel->setStores([1,2]);
$pageModel->save();
```

Comment: I've used setStore method ))